# Как лучше хранить и работать с маркерными байтами и битовыми масками

Tags: c#

Мне при обработке полученных байт надо делать несколько вещей с байтами.

1: Проверить байты на соответвие маркерам или установить байт равный маркеру. Вот два варианта:

```
public enum Marker : byte
{
    Marker1 = 0x0F,
    Marker2 = 0x80,
}

public const byte MARKER1 = 0x0F;
public const byte MARKER2 = 0x80;

public static void TestMarkers()
{
    byte gettedByte = GetRandomByte();

    Marker marker = (Marker)gettedByte;
    if (marker == Marker.Marker1) { }
    else if (marker == Marker.Marker2) { }

    if (gettedByte == MARKER1) { }
    else if (gettedByte == MARKER2) { }

    byte workByte1 = (byte)Marker.Marker1;
    byte workByte2 = MARKER1;
}
```

2: Получить значение, хранящееся под комплексной битовой маской

```
[Flags]
public enum Mask1 : byte
{
    Mask1 = 0x07,
    Mask2 = 0x38,
    Mask3 = 0xC0,
}
public enum Mask2 : byte
{
    Mask1 = 0x07,
    Mask2 = 0x38,
    Mask3 = 0xC0,
}

public const byte MASK1 = 0x07;
public const byte MASK2 = 0x38;
public const byte MASK3 = 0xC0;

public static void ValuesUnderMask()
{
    byte gettedByte = GetRandomByte();

    Mask1 mask1 = (Mask1)gettedByte;
    int value1 = (int)(mask1 & Mask1.Mask1);

    int value2 = gettedByte & (byte)Mask2.Mask1;

    int value3 = gettedByte & MASK1;
}
```

3: Проверка наличия нужных битов

```
public static void TestBits()
{
    byte gettedByte = GetRandomByte();

    Mask1 mask1 = (Mask1)gettedByte;
    bool result1_1 = (mask1 & Mask1.Mask1) == Mask1.Mask1;
    bool result1_2 = mask1.HasFlag(Mask1.Mask1);

    Mask2 mask2 = (Mask2)gettedByte;
    bool result2_1 = (mask2 & Mask2.Mask1) == Mask2.Mask1;
    bool result2_2 = mask2.HasFlag(Mask2.Mask1);

    bool result3_1 = (gettedByte & MASK1) == MASK1;
}
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что разницы в производительности между всеми вариантами не будет? Тк enum везде компилятором будет меняться на байт и следовательно в итоге я получаю одно и тоже. Возможно только HasFlag будет чуть менее эффективней, тк это вызов метода. А синтаксис, который я выберу будет зависеть только от моих личных предпочтений, а не чего либо еще.

Comment: По большей части вопрос вкуса, делайте как вам больше нравится. Что например вам мешает сделать так чтобы GetRandomByte возвращал сразу enum? Тогда и необходимость приведения отпадает.

Comment: Этот метод просто для галочки. Так я получаю просто массив байт и там уже в цикле его обхожу

Comment: Давайте смотреть на этот вопрос как на ревью кода. [Политика относительно вопросов с инспекцией кода (code review)](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1761)